# Error occured while writinga CTE in mysql

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I have the below query in MySQL, but when I execute it I get a syntax error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WITH CTE1 AS ( select u.FirstName,dayname(t.date) as Day, Date_Format(t.Date,"' at line 1

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
select u.FirstName,dayname(t.date) as Day, Date_Format(t.Date,"%Y-%m-%d") As Date,  t.subtask,
IF(subtask='PTO','PTO', hours) as Emphours,

 g1.name
 from user U, task t, groupuser g, `group` g1
where  U.idUser= t.userid and g.userid= U.idUser
and g1.name='Lam-techM' and date >= '2018-11-01' and date <= '2018-11-08'
order by  date asc
)
select * from CTE1;
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is the actual error message you're getting? Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: I am getting error no 1064. Mysql query browser version is 1.2.16

Comment: The query browser version is not important, what is the underlying MySQL version? Versions of MySQL earlier than 8 do not support CTEs